# Use jquery to get a dynamic style value

Tags: jquery

I am playing with the idea of a custom responsive slider and am having difficulty getting the slider container to adjust on "resize". On the intial load all values are correct but when I alert the sliderwid on resize I get NaN... Why does it work on load but not on resize? The code is exactly the same...
Thx

```
var winwid = $(window).width();
    $('.panel').width(winwid);
var panelwid = $('.panel').css('width');
var panels = $('.panel').length;
var sliderwid = parseInt(panels) * parseInt(panelwid)
    $('.slider').width(sliderwid);

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var winwid = $(window).width();
    var panelwid = $('.panel').width(winwid);

    var panels = $('.panel').length;
    var sliderwid = parseInt(panels) * parseInt(panelwid)

    //alert(sliderwid);
    //$('.slider').width(sliderwid);

});
```

Comment: It could be because you're declaring the variables again. Try just using the same ones from before, not using `var` again

Answer (score 0):

Your problem on resize is that you are setting the `panelwid` width value, but this returns a jQuery object.  On load you are getting the panel width which actually returns an integer.

```
var panelwid = $('.panel').width(winwid); // Returns a jQuery Obj
var sliderwid = parseInt(panels) * parseInt(panelwid); // Not a number here
```

You can see this is true by `alert`ing (or better `console.log`) the `panelwid`

```
alert($('.panel').width(winwid));
// Outputs [object Object]
console.log($('.panel').width(winwid));
// Outputs an array with the DOM element
```

The reason for this is so that you can `chain` jQuery methods  If you are unfamiliar with chaining check this out: [Quick Guide: Chaining in jQuery](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)

The fix:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var winwid = $(window).width();
    var $panel = $('.panel');  // Cache the selector
        $panel.width(winwid); // Set the width as in onLoad
    var panelwid = $panel.width(); // return the width - use jQuery to get it without units
    // could be shortened to panelwid = $panel.width(winwid).width();

    var panels = $panel.length;
    var sliderwid = parseInt(panels) * parseInt(panelwid);

    $('.slider').width(sliderwid);
});
```

At least I think that's what you're trying to do.